# How to use the Google Management API to delete unsampled reports that's pending?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

We have Google Analytics Premium.

I would like to delete unsampled reports in Google Sheets / Google Scripts.

I've been getting unsampled reports using the Management API at: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/analytics/v3/analytics.management.unsampledReports.get

I am able to get and schedule unsampled reports using:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/12345/webproperties/33243423/profiles/12345/unsampledReports/?access_token=[access_token]
```

However for the life of me, I can't delete the reports using: (kept on getting User does not have premissions)

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/analytics/v3/analytics.management.unsampledReports.delete

```
DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/12345/webproperties/33243423/profiles/12345/unsampledReports/?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

or

and I can also queue reports using:

```
function deleteAllReports() {
  var logger = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Unsampled Report Logs');
  var lastRow = logger.getLastRow();
  var unsampledReportsArray = logger.getRange(2, lastRow+1, 1, 1).getValues();
   var request = Analytics.Management.UnsampledReports.Delete({
      'accountId': '123456',
      'webPropertyId': 'UA-123456-1',
      'profileId': '7654321',
      'unsampledReportId': '1112223334111222333411'
    });
}
```

Edit:

I'm currently getting the access token from https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token using my client_id, client_secret, and refresh_token.

Roughly:

```
var uri = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
  var payload =
      {
        'client_id' : 'XXXXX',
        'client_secret' : 'XXXXX',
        'grant_type' : 'refresh_token',
        'content_type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'refresh_token' : 'XXXXX'
      };

  var options = 
      { "method" : "POST",
       "muteHttpExceptions" : false,
       "payload" : payload
      };
```

Comment: It sounds like you are authenticating with user that has read only access but not write access. You need to not only authenticate with the `analytics.edit` scope but also be authenticated as the user who has write permissions to that unsampled report.

Comment: You should also include the full error message in your questions: `User does not have sufficient permissions for this XXXX` would help diagnose the problem.

Comment: You shouldn't have to worry about access tokens at all if you are using google apps script. There's an integration already that takes care of that.

Answer (score 2):

The particular error message you are getting "`User does not have sufficient permissions for this XXXX`" indicates one of two things could be wrong with your code:

1. You are authenticated as a user that does not have **edit** permissions on that particular `XXXX`.
2. You have miss identified either the account ID, property ID, view ID, or unsampled report ID, depending on what the `XXXX` is in the error message.

#### More resources

- [Unsampled Reports Reference docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/unsampledReports/delete).
- [Unsampled Reports Developer guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/unsampled-reports).